# iOS: Can't show view after hiding it

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a activityIndicator and a transparent black layer behind it. When something loads I show them like this:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
loadingCover.hidden = NO;
```

And when I hiden them, I just do it like this:

```
[activityIndicator stopAnimating]; //hides on stop
loadingCover.hidden = YES;
```

So far everything works. But somehow if I want to show them again, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
This is how I do it...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [mainView addSubview:loadingCover]; //works
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [loadingCover removeFromSuperview]; //works
}

- (void)refreshRSS:(id)sender {
    [mainView addSubview:loadingCover]; //doesn't work
}
```

EDIT2:
First of all I'm coding with ARC mode and second, loadingCover has been changed to loadingplate, no biggie...

Ok so in my .h file I do this:

```
UIView *loadingplate;
UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
```

And in my .m file in viewDidLoad I do this:

```
CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
loadingplate = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

UIColor *loadingplateColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
[loadingplate setBackgroundColor:loadingplateColor];
loadingplate.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
[loadingIndicator setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
[loadingIndicator startAnimating];

loadingIndicator.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

[loadingplate addSubview:loadingIndicator];
[mainView addSubview:loadingplate];
```

EDI3:
After reading Jasarien's answer I tried this in my .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *loadingPlate;
```

And then in my .m file:

```
@synthesize loadingPlate = _loadingPlate;
```

In this file in viewDidLoad I'm creating the view.

But this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: can you clean up the code in your question? changing `loadingCover` to `loadingplate` and then referring to both `loadingplate` and `loadingPlate` and possibly `_loadingPlate` makes it hard to diagnose your issue. It's possible you simply have a typo. The basic logic you are using is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Please see XJones' comment. This answer is probably wrong.

After Edited question:

It seems that since you're using arc, your `loadingPlate` view is probably being released too soon.

When you alloc and init your `loadingPlate` view, it'll have a retain count of +1, as expected from an alloc/init. Yet, because you're using ARC, after you add it as a subview of your main view, ARC releases it. Effectively the `loadingPlate` view is owned by its super view and when you remove it from the superview, the superview releases it, causing the view to be deallocated. Thus when you try to show it again, it's not there anymore and can't be shown.

The solution to this would be to create a property for your `loadingPlate` view, and give it a 'strong' reference, (effectively the same as declaring the property as a 'retain'). This way, the object that has this property will own the `loadingPlate` view, keeping a strong reference to it.

Comment: Thx for a great answer, I will update my question with the part where I'm creating and initializing the view.

Comment: iVars are strong by default. Adding a property is optional and doesn't change the retain semantics. The comment wrt to `loadingPlate` being "owned" by its superview is misleading. While `loadingPlate` is in a superview, it's true it is retained by that view. But it is also retained in its ivar regardless.

Comment: I see, I didn't know this under ARC. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying loadingCover.hidden = NO does not work? Have you added the view as a subview to the current showing view?

Comment: Well it works one time. Let's say that the view is hidden by default. Then when I want to show it, hidden = NO works, and I can set hidden = YES. But if I now want to set hidden = NO again, it doesn't work :S

Comment: Try removing it from superview instead of hiding it, and then adding to subview when you want it to show again.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the allocation and initialization of that view to the init method. Also, when you call the method to add it again, one thing you can try is to simply check if it exists first probably by:

```
if (!loadingPlate) {
// allocate and initialize again because somehow it has been released.
}
```

At least this way you know if the instance of loadingPlate is still being retained.

Comment: Tried it and the loadingplate is still there

Answer (score 1):

Your basic logic to create, show, and hide `loadingPlate` looks fine. I use a very similar implementation abstracted in a UIView subclass in my apps. All of the answers are stabs in the dark b/c the code you posted doesn't show an obvious problem other than the discrepancies in your iVar names. I decided to add this answer in the hope that it helps you find the solution.

1. You don't need a property. As far as retain semantics go, iVars are `strong` by default. If you do create a property and synthesize it the way you show than be sure to refer to either `self.loadingPlate` or `_loadingPlate` in your code.
2. Make sure you don't have a typo in your iVar name vs your property name. For example, if you have an iVar called `loadingplate` but your property is `loadingPlate` then you will end up with two iVars (`loadingplate` and `loadingPlate`) as properties automatically create iVars if they don't match one already defined.
3. Your logic of creating the `loadingPlate` view in `viewDidLoad` and adding/removing it from the superview as needed is totally fine. Just make aure you don't have `loadingPlate = nil` anywhere other than in `viewDidUnload`.
4. If it's possible for the superview frame size to change you should explicitly set `loadingPlate.frame = mainView.bounds` before adding `loadingView` as a subview. If the frames don't change this won't matter.

If I think of anything else I'll add it later. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `loadingCover` doesn't still have its `hidden` property set to `YES` from the previous time displayed?

Try:

```
- (void)refreshRSS:(id)sender {
    loadingCover.hidden = NO;
    [mainView addSubview:loadingCover]; //doesn't work
}
```

Comment: yes, well my edit was when I tried adding and removing it only, no hide and show

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to use self.loadingplate to call the property strong and make the retain on your view ?